# Does anyone have a ur5 working with moveit and hydro?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-hydro, universal-robots, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tested my hydro installation successfully with pr2 and the pr2_moveit_config and the demo.lauch file and I've updated my ur5 move_group.launch file with the requisite move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService and indicated at groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/mUQqqFsGu9U however when I roslaunch the ur5 demo.lauch or the moveit_planning _execution.launch file rviz comes up for an instant and the I get an exit code -11.  From what I've read this is a seg fault and I'll need to run gdb to further debug however I've tested this on two fresh installation of ubuntu 12.04 x64 and have the same result however the pr2 demo.launch seems to function normally.  Can someone offer some guidance here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128566/does-anyone-have-a-ur5-working-with-moveit-and-hydro?/) by [Rob Farrell](https://answers.ros.org/users/11376/rob-farrell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-12**:
Is your MoveIt config the one from the ROS-Industrial universal_robot repository? Or is it a custom made one?

**Comment by [Rob Farrell](https://answers.ros.org/users/11376/rob-farrell/) on 2014-02-13**:
Currently I'm only trying to get the default ROS-industrial universal_robots hydro-dev repository to work.  I have also tried my own universal_robots and Marco's from below.  All give the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out the stock ur5_moveit_config ur5.srdf has the base_link as part of the manipulator planning group.  Apparently this worked in groovy but not in hydro.  The link can be removed from the manipulator planning group by using the setup_assistant planning groups tab, it can also be seen in the ur5_moveit_config ur5.srdf.

---

Originally posted by [Rob Farrell](https://answers.ros.org/users/11376/rob-farrell/) with karma: 26 on 2014-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-16**:
@Rob Farrell: could you open a ticket about this against the universal_robot repository? This might affect other packages as well. Thanks. The weird thing is that all ROS-I packages include the base_link in the manipulator group, and it works fine as far as I know.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-16**:
It would seem the UR5 MoveIt cfg uses a set of links, instead of a single chain, which is different from other ROS-I cfgs. I'm not sure why it is setup like that, there might be a valid reason.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-03-31**:
Just to follow up on this: https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/pull/45 should fix the described issue.